# Karma+Jasmine+Angular2.0+.net core: how to correctly set the base folder for html templates?

Tags: asp.net, angularjs, karma-jasmine

I have been working on creating a template github project: https://github.com/williamBurgeson/angular2webapi, the intention of which is to provide a sample project with the new Angular 2 framework, against a standard asp.net core / web api setup. (Note this refers to the full 2.0 release, not beta or rc)

I have also referred to https://github.com/juliemr/ng2-test-seed for how to integrate Angular 2 with Karma.

The problem I am getting is that due to the fact that files are served from the wwwroot folder in asp.net core, the Karma runtime (or more specifically probably the Karma web server) is unable to load the html template file which goes with a given component inside the app folder.

In other words, in Angular 2, you would have the component decorator do something like the following:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'my-fancy-border',
  templateUrl: './app/border-component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app/border-component.css'],
  inputs: ['title: title']
})
```

And when served from the web root this is all well and good, however when run in Karma, which uses a "base" virtual folder to serve the site files, it is unable to find the html file, as I suspect it would be looking for '/base/app/border-component.html', and I obviously don't want to hard-code "base" into the typescript source file.

Rather than copy and paste lots of files below it's probably easier to go to the github repo and clone it, if anybody does fancy a stab at answering this.

I'm sure this is an issue which people will come across more and more over the coming months, however as Angular 2 is so new, and there have been so many breaking changes through the beta and rc cycles, there is very sparse documentation.

If anybody does manage to solve this (or I do for that matter), then I'll put that fix into the repo.

Answer (score 0):

Answered my own question!

Referring to http://blog.thoughtram.io/angular/2016/06/08/component-relative-paths-in-angular-2.html, I saw to change the component declaration to the following:-

```
@Component({
  moduleId: module.id,
  selector: 'my-fancy-border',
  templateUrl: './border-component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./border-component.css'],
  inputs: ['title: title']
})
```

Note that I have added the moduleId member as module.id, and amended the paths to be relative to the current folder. It works!

I will be committing this change and uploading to github in a few moments.